# How to compile source which needs -lopencv_contrib on Ubuntu?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I want to compile [this](https://github.com/elespuru/elespuru-cvglsl) code

I installed glut via `sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev`

To install OpenCV, i run a script from [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV), went to `build` subfolder of `OpenCV` and run `make install`

I got an error

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -o cvglsl *.c -lglut -lGLU -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_gpu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gpu
```

The I followed [instructions](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) from a contrib repo:

1)I cloned the repo to a `build` folder.

2)Inside `build` I run `cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=./opencv_contrib/modules ..`

3)Inside build I used `make install` once again

The error persists. How can I install `opencv_contrib` properly?

Comment: if your code wants -lopencv_contrib , it is opencv2.4, not opencv3.0.

Comment: also, the original code is unfortunately using opencv's deprecated c-api, which must no more be used.

Comment: rather look for more up-to-date code. everything, that tries to use opencv from c is doomed.